# Android not making another table in the database

Tags: android, database

Here is my code in Database Creation

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TBL_NAME_Arth + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "RECIPE_NAME TEXT,ING_1 TEXT,ING_2 TEXT,ING_3 TEXT,ING_4 TEXT,ING_5 TEXT,ING_6 TEXT,ING_7 TEXT,ING_8 TEXT,ING_9 TEXT,ING_10 TEXT+" +
            "ING_12 TEXT,ING_12 TEXT,ING_13 TEXT,ING_14 TEXT,ING_15 TEXT,ING_16 TEXT,ING_17 TEXT,ING_18 TEXT,ING_19 TEXT,ING_20 TEXT)");

    db.execSQL("create table " + TBL_NAME_Dia + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "RECIPE_NAME TEXT,ING_1 TEXT,ING_2 TEXT,ING_3 TEXT,ING_4 TEXT,ING_5 TEXT,ING_6 TEXT,ING_7 TEXT,ING_8 TEXT,ING_9 TEXT,ING_10 TEXT+" +
            "ING_12 TEXT,ING_12 TEXT,ING_13 TEXT,ING_14 TEXT,ING_15 TEXT,ING_16 TEXT,ING_17 TEXT,ING_18 TEXT,ING_19 TEXT,ING_20 TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_NAME_Arth);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_NAME_Dia);

}
```

This codes is for calling the creation `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);`

Comment: Uninstall your app and reinstall again. `onCreate` won't get called if database is already there. If you want to modify your DB uninstall and install again.

Comment: How can I if I am using Virtual Device ?

Comment: if you update the DB Version number, `onUpgrade()` will  be called

Comment: Why can't you uninstall the app if you are using "Virtual Device"?

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `onCreate(db);` after the drop statements in `onUpgrade()` method.
Currently, you are creating your tables and dropping them after that.

But, in `onUpgrade()` method you should drop the existing tables first and than create the new ones.

Comment: Sirs, another question, if I have now the data in my table How or what would I do for it not to duplicate ? Coz I got alot of data in my table and it is all the same everytime I execute my app it makes a data on the table.

Comment: Remove the repeated data. And if you cannot do that, check whether it already exists in the table or not. If yes, don't insert it.